# Generate a scaffold controller inside an uppercased namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the apn_on_rails gem, that has few models under a namespace named APN.
What is the correct way to generate a scaffold controller for the APN::Device model and route to it correctly?

Comment: I can suggest to create it by hand.

Comment: At the moment I made a model in global namespace wich single-table-inherit from the one in the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create it just by hands, manualy.
2. As far as Ruby uses underscore instead of CamelCase you can try this:

> rails g scaffold a_p_n::Device ...

which will generate this model for you:

```
class APN::Device < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

in `app/models/a_p_n/device.rb`

and it will generate routes for you:

```
namespace :a_p_n do 
  resources :devices 
end
```

Comment: Still have some trouble: I generate the scaffold_controller (the model already exist in the gem) with `rails g scaffold_controller` and add the route to that controller, but when I go to localhost:/a_p_n/devices/ this error raise up: `Routing Error
uninitialized constant APN::DevicesController`. I think you are near to the solution.

Comment: I am getting `undefined method [model]_path for class ##` on the `index` page as well? It doesn't have a form there. I have created controller using `scaffold_controller [controllername] --model-name=[model]`